# Como ler um arquivo e salvar cada linha em uma posição de um vetor em C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estou aprendendo a utilizar C# no Visual Studio 2019. Quero ler um arquivo texto e salvar cada linha em
uma posição de um vetor do tipo string. Porém quando clico no "button1" para ler o arquivo e salvar no vetor, ele da  o seguinte erro:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.'
Os outros botões funcionam normalmente. Não sei onde estou errando.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Manipular_Arquivos
{
    public partial class Editor : Form
    {
        
        int count = 0, i=0;
        string[] dados;
        public Editor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
/*É neste ponto minha dúvida. O arquivo que quero ler está da seguinte maneira:
6
7
8.3
1.0
Cada número em uma linha. Mas não consigo salvar cada linha em uma posição do vetor de string "dados"*/
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string nomeArquivo = textBox1.Text;
            StreamReader leitor = new StreamReader(nomeArquivo + ".txt");
            while (!leitor.EndOfStream)
            {
                string linha = leitor.ReadLine();
                richTextBox1.Text += linha + "\n";
                dados[count] = linha;
                count++;
            }
            leitor.Close();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string nomeArq = textBox1.Text;
            StreamWriter escritor = new StreamWriter((nomeArq + ".txt"), true);
            escritor.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Text);
            escritor.Close();
        }
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "";

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "";
            string nome = textBox1.Text;
            StreamWriter escritor = new StreamWriter(nome + ".txt");
            escritor.WriteLine("");
            escritor.Close();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Principal novo = new Principal();
            this.Close();
            novo.Show();
            
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string nomeArq = textBox1.Text;
            StreamWriter escritor = new StreamWriter(nomeArq + ".txt");
            escritor.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Text);
            escritor.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Porque não está dando certo?

Foi declarado um `array` de `string`, mas, não foi inicializado a quantidade de posições que esse `array` de `string` terá, exemplo da declaração:

```
string[] dados; // não foi informado a quantidade de posições
```

e no caso deveria então ser informado a quantidade de posições da seguinte forma:

```
string[] dados =  new string[6];
```

mas, o problema nessa declaração é que o código ainda não sabe a quantidade de linhas do arquivo texto e isso deixa o código restrito somente a essa quantidade de elementos.

> Solução para esse problema

Utilize uma lista *tipado*, que será incrementada de forma transparente pelo código, não se preocupando com a quantidade que virá da leitura desse arquivo de texto, exemplo:

```
List<string> dados = new List<string>();
```

e resumindo no seu código utilize o método `Add` para adicionar na lista as linhas contidas no arquivo de texto:

```
using (StreamReader str = new StreamReader("./d.txt", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    string line = "";
    while ((line = str.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        dados.Add(line);
    }
}
```

***Observação:*** Se tiver a quantidade com certeza de linhas que esse arquivo `.txt` retorne pode utilizar como demonstrado `string[] dados =  new string[6];` e no caso para atribuição coloque `dados[0] = line;`, onde 0 e a posição do `array`.

Comment: Funcionou! Realmente não sabia que havia a maneira List<string>, me ajudou muito. Obrigada!